# how to declare var without spaces in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to declare a variable but the value is coming runtime from some text strings.Can someone please suggest howto remove the spaces and line breaks so that variable is declare properly?

```
var view_Invoice= '

     invoice

';
```

It giving an error.

Comment: Trim it before putting it out. Else `view_Invoic = view_Invoic.trim()`

Comment: If you're using a programming language like Java, PHP, Python, Ruby, etc to generate Javascript code, use methods provided by these languages, for example, in Java you can use the method `trim()` as follow `var view_Invoice = '<%= string.trim()%>'`

Comment: @isherwood that dupe answer is wrong for this case.

Comment: Yeah... I think everyone except Ele is completely missing the question here.  OP needs [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (as long as IE support isn't needed) or a server side solution.

Answer (score 3):

Trim it before putting it out in javascript.
Changing the string delimiter also works in some browsers (which support ES6):

```
var view_Invoice= `

     invoice

`;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental reason for *why* you're seeing this error is that the variable doesn't start with [a valid character](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers):

> An identifier must start with $, _, or any character in the Unicode categories > “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”, “Titlecase letter (Lt)”,
>   “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”, or “Letter number (Nl)”.

In your case, the easiest way to fix the problem will be to trim the white space from the beginning of the string.  If you *only* want the whitespace at the beginning of the string to be removed, you can use

```
.replace(/^\s+/g, "")
```

but if you're happy for the whitespace at both the beginning and end of the whitespace removed you can use the [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) function